# How to edit Label while running

Tags: vb.net-2010

I've been making a class schedule system for my school project.

I just wanted to ask how can I edit labels while running, so when the user double clicks the label they can put the data they want for their class schedule.

Is there anymore convenient way to do this instead of using labels?

Answer (score -1):

You can't do this while running, but i can help you make a Text Box shown when the users hit double clicks on the label to put the data they want.

I Hope My Answer Was Useful To You.